# SELECT @variable do not work in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

```
var client = new require("mysql-pool").MySQLPool({...});

client.query( 
   "SET @counter := 0, @type := 'asd'; select @counter, @type"   ,

    function (error, result, fields) {
       if (error) {
           throw error;
       }else{
          cb(result, fields);
       }
    });

(
```

query work just fine in workbench or dbForge, and mysql-pool also works, but only without `@variable_name` )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that ?

```
"SELECT @counter := 0, @type := 'asd'"
```

But TYPE could be RESERVED name, so consider to use sth. else ie. ENTITY_TYPE